# How to animate UITableView without resetting table position, similar to Apple Mail app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a tableView which has a button to put it into a pseudoEditing mode. In this mode this cells "shift right/left" to display a checkbox on the left hand side. The process is not unlike how the Mail app "Edit" button works.

The way i am doing this now is by setting a pseudoEditing flag and then reloading the table and if the flag is set then the cell is drawn differently. I have also put this inside an animation block which gives me the shifting effect:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"cell shift" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kEventActionViewAnimationDuration];

cell.eventName.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingFirstIndentedRect :     kFirstLabelRect;
cell.eventLocationName.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingSecondIndentedRect : kSecondaryLabelRect;
cell.eventStartDate.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingThirdIndentedRect : kThirdLabelRect;
cell.eventStartEndTime.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kPseudoEditingFourthIndentedRect : kFourthLabelRect;
cell.imageView.frame = (self.pseudoEditing) ? kImageViewIndentedRect : kImageViewRect;
cell.rsvpImageView.hidden = !self.pseudoEditing;

[UIView commitAnimations];

return cell;
```

My problem though is that i need to reload the table in order for the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to be called to update the cells which in turn resets the table position to the top of the tableView. I *could* then set the table position to the position it was before hitting the edit button using something like scrollToIndexPath:... This however wouldnt work because the table would scroll to the top and then back to the previous cell which i dont want.

So is there a way to reload the tableCells in a tableView without having the tableView change scroll position, similar to how the Mail app does it?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `-layoutSubviews`. In that method, you'll check `UITableViewCell`s `editing` property and determine the frames of the content views accordingly. Any changes made in `-layoutSubviews` will automatically animate when the cells editing mode is changed. Simply setting `editing` on the table view will automatically perform that change to all cells.

Comment: This sounds like a really clean way to do it although after trying it i keep getting the Delete Icon show up on the left side after the cell has shifted. The problem is that im not sure how to use my own image instead of the delete icon? Secondly, i am not using a typical edit mode and instead im trying  to duplicate the Mail app where once in "Edit" mode you can toggle different states by selecting the row. It seems that the tableView does not trigger the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method when in editing mode??

Comment: Set `allowsSelectionDuringEditing` on the table view to `YES`. You'll also need to implement the UITableViewDelegate method `- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`. This will hide the delete button and ensure that `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be called while the table view and its cells are in editing mode.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't reload the table view for this at all. Make your cells have a property like `multiEditing`. When you begin editing, iterate over the `visibleCells` array of the table view and set the property in an animation block (the cell itself could perform the animation, similar to the existing `setEditing:animated:` method). For new cells, simply set it without animation after dequeueing/creating them.